почему не учитываються паддинги container в секции?
первый раз с таким столкнулась что заданные паддинги на контейнер не видны при работе,т.е. они не работают. Что делать?
песочница в комментах
это фактически что имею



.container {
  max-width: 340px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.works-cont-img {
  background-color: #7a3145;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.works-image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.works-image {
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 335px;
  height: 450px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
<section>
  <div class="container works-container">
    <div class="works-cont-img">
      <div class="works-image">
        <img src="https://www.catstep.ru/upload/webp/70/iblock/76b/76bb21df67230809c5d8909cc81f9930.webp" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>




https://codepen.io/Taia-Mazur/pen/poBKdrM

На Вашем же скриншоте paddings выделены зеленым, либо что Вы под этим подразумеваете?

все что в контейнере не имеет его паддингов

https://codepen.io/Taia-Mazur/pen/poBKdrM здесь тоже самое происходит

Одной ссылки на codepen было вполне достаточно. У Вашего контейнера есть паддинги по 20px слева и справа, чего еще Вы ожидаете?

добавь картинку на которой видно, где ты ожидаешь увидеть паддинги, которых нет. сейчас все паддинги отображаются корректно

В стилях где используете padding и margin добавьте position:relative;
